# Other classes to be able to access an arraylist of object type

Tags: java, arraylist, static

I want to create a class that manipulates files, and I want it to read in a file and add it to an arraylist of object type (lets just say classLists).

How do I declare the arraylist so that my other classes can access it. Lets just say teacher and principal.

What would making it static do also?

```
  public ArrayList<classList> list = new ArrayList<classList>();
  public Static ArrayList<classList> list = new ArrayList<classList>();
```

Comment: Static should be lowercase while a class identifier like `classList` should be camel cased (`ClassName`) and should mean something useful, as classList doesn't look like a class identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Making a data member static means that all the instance can share the same value of that particular static member of class.. And you can also access that member without instantiation of class. Other classes object can also access the static member of class.

```
public static ArrayList<classList> list = new ArrayList<classList>();
```